# Capture screenshot of hidden desktop

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, gdi+, gdi

I am using virtual desktops on Windows using simple app that i coded myself in C++, i was wondering if there is way to capture screenshot of secondary/hidden desktop ?
I know that i can do SwitchDesktop -> capture screenshot -> SwitchDesktop, but it doesnt sound like good solution....

Maybe i run some window in the hidden desktop, to get its hwnd and SOMEHOW to use it to capture the entire screen ?

I have run Spy++ but seems it not finding windows that dont belong to currently active desktop.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `PrintWindow` might be useful.

Comment: Probably i have to pass HWND to the desktop window but how do i get HWND ? Also will it work executed from other desktop or PrintWindow must be executed from the same desktop i want to capture... its kinda confusing me...

Comment: I'm not aware of communication methods between multiple desktops. I'd use that to make a nice multiple desktops app if I did :/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4580520/take-a-screenshot-of-a-desktop-created-using-createdesktop-api

Comment: Flot2011, this method is helping me to capture just Window from the other desktop but not the entire desktop.... So still looking for help.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you could live without XP support this [article](http://spazzarama.com/2009/02/12/screen-capture-with-vista-dwm/) explains how to use [DWM API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa969540.aspx) for getting screenshot of the invisible desktop.

Comment: Thanks i cant live without XP but maybe will be useful anyways :)